# I want to compute the sum of first N even numbers based on the user input N using recursive function

Tags: python, function, loops

**I want to compute the sum of first N even numbers based on the user input N using recursive function.**

**For example:**

**Sample Input N: 5**

**Sample Output: 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = 30**

*I did my code in 2 ways but both of them gave wrong outputs. I'm doing something wrong in the function part sorting number in the loop. So I need some help!*

```
n = int(input("Enter a nmuber: "))
for i in range(1,n+1):
   for d in range(0,i+1,2):
       print(d)
```

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
def get_even(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1,2):
        d += i
        print(d)
```

Comment: I don't see any recursion here (although recursion is a poor solution in any case). Can you clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

**Code**

```
def sum_even(n):
    # Base case
    if n <= 1:
        return 0
    
    if n % 2:
        # odd n
        return sum_even(n - 1)     # sum from next smaller even
    else:
        # even n
        return n + sum_even(n - 2) # current plus sum from next smaller even

# Usage
n = int(input('Enter a nmuber: '))
print(sum_even(n))
```